# Python-Flask-Postgresql DB sql Locks

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I tried looking in the documentation of Flask and SQLAlchemy but I couldn't find the answer...

Do the sessions used with SQLAlchemy automatically lock the DB?  I do a read (let's say it takes a long time) and it seems to block out any other reads I am trying to do on my Postgres DB.  Is this something I have to configure manually on Postgres using constraints or is there something I can change with Flask / SQLAlchemy?

Thanks

Comment: The short answer is yes, flask-sqlalchemy (and anything else your flask app is busy with) will block further code processing. It's a bit hard to tell without seeing some code and knowing more details why the database query is taking long. if that can be improved, then it should. If indeed the SQL query is very intricate, processes a large number of records, etc. it should be done in the background, which will affect how you design the app. Please provide more details so others can see what the actual problem may be.

Comment: I'm not a python programmer, but it's hard to believe that any SELECT query would lock the tables (or database) it's using. That would kill all performance and makes no sense at all from a database perspective. A database like PostgreSQL is made for concurrent usage.

Comment: Oh yeah, postgres is not the issue here, it's the python side of things, like waiting for a single query to finish. This is different than issuing multiple queries to the database concurrently, by any mechanism.